# Database error when porting over from localhost to server using SQL SERVER Management Studio

Tags: php, visual-studio-2013, ssms

What I'm Doing: Taking in basic form data and using a stored procedure to put it into a database. Very simple, just make sure the data types don't conflict. There are no triggers.
I tested out my code on localhost before porting it over and it works perfectly. However, when i port it over to the website we are using im getting the error -

"Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -14 [code] => -14 [2] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_execute. [message] => An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_execute. ) ) 1"

I'm passing my reference and I wrote a similar app just like the one im trying to do now never received this error.

Additionally, I tried just passing in 1 part of the post into the data base and got the same error.

I know it says invalid parameters but everything matches. I even rewrote the database but nothing works.

Any ideas?

Comment: No code, no help. but the error message seems to clear enough, you're calling `sqlserv_execute()` incorrectly.

Comment: Not sure if i can offer the code. However, if you read the post it works perfectly when i tested it locally. Writes to the data base and everything. As soon as i port it it doesn't work. Im more asking if anyone has any idea on why that is happening.